# Sbt ( new version 1.0.4) assembly failure

Tags: eclipse, scala, sbt, sbt-assembly

I have been trying to build fat jar for some time now. I got assembly.sbt in project folder and it looks like below

```
addSbtPlugin("com.eed3si9n" % "sbt-assembly" % "0.14.6")
```

and my build.sbt looks like below

```
name := "cool"
version := "0.1"
scalaVersion := "2.11.8"

resolvers += "Hortonworks Repository" at 
"http://repo.hortonworks.com/content/repositories/releases/"
resolvers += "Hortonworks Jetty Maven Repository" at 
"http://repo.hortonworks.com/content/repositories/jetty-hadoop/"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
"org.apache.spark" % "spark-streaming_2.10" % "1.6.1.2.4.2.0-258" % 
"provided",
"org.apache.spark" % "spark-streaming-kafka-assembly_2.10" % 
"1.6.1.2.4.2.0-258"
 )


assemblyMergeStrategy in assembly := {
case PathList("META-INF", xs @ _*) => MergeStrategy.discard
case x => MergeStrategy.first
}
```

i get below error

```
assemblyMergeStrategy in assembly := {
 ^
C:\Users\sreer\Desktop\workspace\cool\build.sbt:14: error: not found: 
value assembly
assemblyMergeStrategy in assembly := {
                     ^
C:\Users\sreer\Desktop\workspace\cool\build.sbt:15: error: not found: 
value PathList
case PathList("META-INF", xs @ _*) => MergeStrategy.discard
  ^
C:\Users\sreer\Desktop\workspace\cool\build.sbt:15: error: star patterns 
must correspond with varargs parameters
case PathList("META-INF", xs @ _*) => MergeStrategy.discard
                             ^
C:\Users\sreer\Desktop\workspace\cool\build.sbt:15: error: not found: 
value MergeStrategy
case PathList("META-INF", xs @ _*) => MergeStrategy.discard
                                   ^
C:\Users\sreer\Desktop\workspace\cool\build.sbt:16: error: not found: 
value MergeStrategy
case x => MergeStrategy.first
       ^
[error] Type error in expression
```

I get this Type error and seems like it won't recognize keys like "assemblyMergeStrategy". I use sbt new version 1.0.4 and latest version of eclipse IDE for scala.

I have tried changing version of sbt and still no result, went through whole document at https://github.com/sbt/sbt-assembly, made sure there were no typos and suggestions mentioned in other threads weren't of much help ( mostly questions are about older versions of sbt). If some one could guide me that would be very helpful. Thanks.